# Distribute application to internal tester from play store

Tags: android, google-play, android-build, google-play-console, google-play-internal-testing

I'm releasing application first time on play store and before I release it to production I want to release the application for internal testers and for that I have uploaded the build. Also, added the list of testers and other details. Now. it's showing me "Full rollout" under "Internal test" in "Internal test track"  but testers were not got any update and "Opt-in URL" is not getting generated. What could be the issue?

Check below image for the same,

[image]

Comment: It looks like your app is not yet published. Did you finish all Play Store configuration? You need that to publish the app for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved after 48 hours.

So, I get to know that it will take 48 hours to generate the "Opt-in URL" in the very first time for the application in the "Internal test" section.